# Cleaning HTML using python

Tags: python, html

I have the below code however i am receiving an error. I am trying to get the text from an html file between Tag1 and Tag2
without the for loop the code is working (for one file) however when looping in a directory it is not

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
import os
import bleach
import re
rootdir = mydirectory
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        url = file
        print url
        raw = urlopen(url).read()
        type(raw)
        Tag1 = raw.find("""<div class="song-text">""")
        Tag2 = raw.rfind("""<div style="text-align:center;padding-bottom:10px;">""")
        Cleaned = raw[Tag1+23:Tag2]
        print Cleaned
```

> Error message: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "TestClean.py", line 12, in 
>       raw = urlopen(url).read()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 463, in open_file
>       return self.open_local_file(url)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 477, in open_local_file
>       raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'paroles-a-beautiful-lie.html'

Comment: I think you try to open the file at the wrong location. `url` is just the filename. You might want to use `os.path.join` to concatenate `subdir` and `url`. BTW, use a HTML parser to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Error message indicates a lack of file. `os.walk` returns only the name of the file, but not the full path to it. 1) Take the `path = os.path.join(subdir, file)` 2) Read the file `open(path).read()`without `urlopen`

Answer (score 0):

It is well clear from the Traceback that it is not able to find 'paroles-a-beautiful-lie.html' file. I would suggest you to go step by step.

1. Comment the code below 'print url'.
2. Check whether you are getting proper url.
3. Then proceed with your next step - finding process.